# Another Appaerance of Pi: Is this probability distribution relevant?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, pi

The other day i was wondering in my computer about functions who would look like a gaussian distribution. I first tought of the function:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} $$
Whose max value is $f(0) = 1$. However, we have that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \mathbb{d}x = \pi $$
And hence this cannot be a probability distribution. So basically i kept trying to find a constant $c^2$ such that the integral would evaluate $1$. And, for my (at first glance) surprise:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 + \pi^2} \mathbb{d}x = 1 $$
(Since the primitive of $f(x)$ is $\operatorname{arctan}x$, this is not very surprising).
I found wonderful that $\pi$ appeared in such an unexpected way.

My question is: Does this probability distribution has any relevance like the other we normally use in the study of probability? (Gaussian, Exponential, Poisson, etc)
For me it seems like such a fine, simple probability distribution. Why haven't i ever seen it anywhere?

Comment: This is the Cauchy distribution. I think it's closely connected with Poisson processes but it has been a while since I studied them.

Comment: This random variable is a constant multiple of standard Cauchy random variable. It is somewhat uncommon because it has no well-defined mean.

Comment: This is the PDF of $\pi$ times a standard Cauchy random variable. Cauchy distributions are indeed amongst the commonest examples of non integrable distributions. "Why haven't i ever seen it anywhere?" Because you didn't search [so much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)?